SpriteRenderer changing sprite on runtime not working in android build?
If you try creating test scene, with a simple script to change sprite every a period of time.
The sprite doesn't change, but if you try to log the changed sprite name, you'll see it has changed successfully. Which means only the visual is not changing.
Testing on Unity 6000.0.3f1, and on android S24 Ultra
My TestSpriteRendererChange.cs script
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestSpriteRendererChange : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
    [SerializeField] private Sprite[] sprites;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(ChangeSprites());
    }

    private IEnumerator ChangeSprites()
    {
        var index = 0;

        foreach (var sprite in sprites)
        {
            Debug.Log($"before sprite: {spriteRenderer.sprite.name}");

            spriteRenderer.sprite = sprite;

            Debug.Log($"after sprite: {spriteRenderer.sprite.name}");

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);

            index++;
        }

        if (index == sprites.Length)
        {
            index = 0;

            StopCoroutine(nameof(ChangeSprites));
            StartCoroutine(nameof(ChangeSprites));
        }
    }
}

Behaviour in unity editor

Behaviour in android device

This issue is related to URP 2D only, it works just fine in built-in-RP 2D projects.

Well. One consideration is i thought android was 30fps so 0.1s would be 3 frames. The fact its changing shape but not texture is curious but the graphics capabilities are considerably less. Do you get any additional messages in the player log files

@BugFinder Timing is not the issue, I increased it to 1f which is one second, and the issue is the same

Ok but as it went unmentioned it was a good place to start.  Having to remake the component seems a big hammer and while of course it does reset that sounds like something you should report to unity.

Yes I filed a report to unity

This was an actual bug in unity 6000.0.3f1, so I did the following
As a workaround for this issue, I've modified my script as follow :-
I changed my TestSpriteRendererChange.cs to the following :-
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class TestSpriteRendererChange : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject spriteGO;
    [SerializeField] private Sprite[] sprites;
 
    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(ChangeSprites());
    }
 
    private IEnumerator ChangeSprites()
    {
        var index = 0;
 
        foreach (var sprite in sprites)
        {
            // check if SpriteRenderer exists
            var hasComponent = spriteGO.TryGetComponent(out SpriteRenderer sr);
 
            // we could cash reference to sortingLayer and sortingOrder to avoid reset
            if (hasComponent)
            {
                // we remove the component if exists
                Destroy(sr);
            }
 
            // wait for end of frame to avoid null reference error
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
 
            // we add the SpriteRenderer component again
            var spriteRenderer = spriteGO.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
 
            spriteRenderer.sprite = sprite;
 
            Debug.Log($"after sprite: {spriteRenderer.sprite.name}");
 
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
 
            index++;
        }
 
        if (index == sprites.Length)
        {
            index = 0;
 
            StopCoroutine(nameof(ChangeSprites));
            StartCoroutine(nameof(ChangeSprites));
        }
    }
}

By removing the SpriteRenderer component and adding it again, resolves the issue.
Let me know if there is a better solution.
